# Error config database mysql with play framework

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.6

I starting with Java and Play Framework, and I try to config the database mysql.
But I have the error following :

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors: 1) No implementation for play.db.Database annotated with @play.db.NamedDatabase(value=baseplay) was bound.
```

I have my class :

```
    // inject "orders" database instead of "default"
@javax.inject.Singleton
public class JavaApplicationDataBase implements IWidgetRepository {

    private Database db;
    private DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext;

    @Inject
    public JavaApplicationDataBase(@NamedDatabase("baseplay") Database db, DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext) {
        this.db = db;
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
    }
```

the file config 'application.conf' :

```
# Default database configuration
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/baseplay"
db.default.username=root
db.default.password="root"
```

and the config file 'build.sbt' :

```
name := """play-java-forms-example"""

version := "2.6.x"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.12", "2.12.4")

testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-a", "-v"))

libraryDependencies += guice

EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile, compile in Test) 

libraryDependencies += javaJdbc

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.41"
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to change the config db name to whatever you want to inject in @NamedDatabase("baseplay"). So in this case you config would be like:

```
# Default database configuration
db.baseplay.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.baseplay.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/baseplay"
db.baseplay.username=root
db.baseplay.password="root"
```